# Select2 refresh losing all classes? Change single option text

Tags: jquery-select2

I need to change an option text inside a jQuery Select2.

The following works to change the hidden input value

```
var select2 = $('#myselect2id');
var option = select2.find("option[value='" + 13 + "']");
option.text("this is the new text");
```

But after that i would need to change the displayed text.
Looking around, i found it can be done by calling

```
select2.select2();
```

to rebuild the select2. It works, but it loses all the html classes it had.
And that means a completely different appearance.

Update:
The select2 is used with an hidden select field (it's based on Kartik's Yii2 Select2 widget)
Anyway when the select2 function is called, the spans built by the widget lose their classes

Comment: can you create a fiddle, i created one, cannot see any issues: https://jsfiddle.net/cnyrm1s4/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f401gn2u/
Ignore the bottom select, usually there are some jquery function hiding the original select i think.
Anyway you can see clicking on the button the first select gets the text change but loses the "coolstyling" class.